# In Unix,why directory is a file and an allocation bitmap is not

Tags: file, unix, bitmap, operating-system, filesystems

I'm currently preparing an entrance of a graduate school.

And one of a past-year-question is:

In. Unix system,which of the following is not a file ?

A.a device special file

B.a directory

C.a symbolic link

D.an allocation bitmap

E.the standard input(console)

And the official answer is D.

I understand A is a file .But why B and E are also files?

And why bitmap is not a file?

Comment: I think *an allocation bitmap* means allocate memory for bitmap. It's not stored as file.

Comment: No he's probably talking about *free space bitmap*... Question is related to filesystem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But why B and E are also files?

Because they can all be listed and accessed by their names on a file system. All files, regardless of their types all have a common set of properties like owner, group, permissions, access, change, and modification time, inode number, number of links and a few others.

> And why bitmap is not a file?

A bitmap might be stored in a file, or not. An allocation bitmap is commonly stored in memory; it is an operating system, a library, or an application object, but not necessarily a file.

Comment: Got it. Thank you!